# Calculate amount of users who was active two days in a row mysql

Tags: mysql, date, count, self-join

I need to calculate amount of users who was active two days in a row.
I have table 'activity'

user_id | login_time

1234    |  2019-04-15

1456    |  2019-04-15

1234    |  2019-04-16

1456    |  2019-04-17

How I can calculate amount of users who was active on 15th and 16th too.

Comment: Which mysql version are you using?

Comment: 15th and 16th of any month?  Of any year?  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: 15th and 16th of current month like in example. 

@nbk version of mysql 5.7.28

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, i've tried already - 1st try - count amount of days and filter them by having count(days(login_time)) = 2, but that was non-effective

Answer (score 0):

For only two days it is easy, but if you want to calculate for a month, you have to use user variables.

Edit: 
for the current Month

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(user_id)
FROM
  (SELECT
     user_id
   FROM 
     (SELECT `user_id`, `login_time` FROM user_login 
      WHERE `login_time` BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()),'-15') 
        AND CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()),'-16'
      GROUP BY `user_id`, `login_time`)
     user_login)
GROUP By user_id
HAVING COUNT( user_id) = 2) a
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_login (
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `login_time` date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO user_login
>   (`user_id`, `login_time`)
> VALUES
>   ('1234', '2019-04-15'),
>   ('1456', '2019-04-15'),
>   ('1456', '2019-04-15'),
>   ('1234', '2019-04-16'),
>   ('1456', '2019-04-17');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> COUNT(user_id)
> FROM
> (SELECT
> user_id
> FROM 
> (SELECT `user_id`, `login_time` FROM user_login
> WHERE `login_time` BETWEEN '2019-04-15' AND '2019-04-16'  GROUP BY `user_id`, `login_time`)
> user_login
> GROUP By user_id
> HAVING COUNT( user_id) = 2) a
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(user_id) |
> | -------------: |
> |              1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e733586920e677893435e754fec9448a)*

Comment: Maybe you know another way to make it? Because when I apply this query to my table I have in result users who was active only in one of this days and also users who was active for two days in row (  I've add count(user_id) in select - it show 2 days, but if I checked current user in raw data - it show only one day activity (

Comment: I understand problem - if user have 2 logins per day - it count like he have 2 logins per period. 
How I can calculate distinct logins per day?

Comment: Sure i changed the query